# Overriding Python's Hashing Function in Dictionary

Tags: python, hash, dictionary, hashtable

I am trying to create a custom hash function for some object that I'll be hashing into a dictionary. The hashing function is unique (not the standard Python one). This is very important to me: to use the unique function. Each key's value is a list.

Assuming I override `__hash__` and end up coming up with the right hash number for an object. Would:

```
dict = {}
dict[number_here] = value
```

hash the value into the position number `number_here`, or would it still be at the position that Python's hash table would compute for that number?

Printing `dict` only shows the items and not which position they're that. However, when I do `hash(4)`, the result is 4. So I'm assuming this means integers are hashed to their respective locations?

Could someone please verify my findings or explain to me if I'm wrong?

Comment: This video might make things a little clearer: http://t.co/ZqEWs8MD

Comment: @ShawnChin: and that is why link only answers(and comments) are frowned upon.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The python `dict` implementation uses the hash value to both sparsely store values based on the key and to avoid collisions in that storage. It uses the result of `hash()` as a *starting point*, it is not the definitive position.

Thus, although `hash(4)` returns `4`, the exact 'position' in the underlying C structure is also based on what *other* keys are already there, and how large the current table is. The python hash table is resized as needed (items added), for example.

Since a dict has no ordering, this is not something you need to worry about, or can hope to influence. If you need ordering in a dict, use the `collections.OrderedDict()` implementation instead, which keeps track of ordering separately.

#### The details of the python hash table implementation

You may want to read up on how hash tables work on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table); Python uses open addressing for it's implementation.

When selecting a slot in the table, the modulus of the hash value (an integer) and the current table size is taken, thus on a table of size 32, so the key `45`, hash value `45` would initially be stored in slot 14.

If there is a collision (there already is something else stored in slot 14 and it's not the integer `45`), then the slot value is *perturbed* until an empty slot is found or the same key is found instead. Perturbing is done with the formula:

```
perturb = slot = hash
while slot_is_full and item_in_slot_is_not_equal_to_key:
    slot = (5*slot) + 1 + perturb
    perturb >>= 5
```

So, when there is a collision, another slot is picked at progressively smaller steps until it scans the whole table. Note that the table will already have been resized to make space if necessary.

In order for this to work correctly, custom types need both a [`__hash__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method *and* need to implement [`__eq__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to determine if two instances represent the same key. Matching hash values is *not* enough. For the `dict` implementation to consider two instances to represent the exact same key, both their hash values must match, and they must return True for the `==` equality operator. Such objects are considered [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable).

(For Python 2.x, implementing the [`__cmp__()` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) would do instead of implementing `__eq__()`; support for this has been removed in Python 3).

Comment: I have a question : on my machine hash('abc') == hash(-1600925533). I can have a dictionary with both values as keys. Shouldn't there be some kind of hash collision? or python does python use some other hash function, not builtin hash()?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I want Python to handle collisions and it's okay if it reorders it. But if two different objects return hash `4`, they will always definitely hash to the same key, right?

Comment: Hash collisions can and do occur, and the hash table implementation is able to deal with these collisions.

Comment: @Darksky: no, not unless those keys are *equal*. `hash(key1) == hash(key2)` is not enough to be considered the same key. `key1 == key2` must also be true.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn Pieters gave an excellent answer. I just wanted to add that the [CPython source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c) is well documented and also an excellent place to look into the details of the Python Dictionary implementation. Last I checked, the pertinent comments were on lines 33-135.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly change the hashing of a `Dictionary`, you can do indirectly custom hash your `Dictionary` based on one or more keys in it.

Wrap it in a custom class:

```
class Foo:
def __init__(self, foo):
    self.foo_id = foo.get('id') # id is unique for all instances of Foo

def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, Foo) and self.foo_id == other.foo_id

def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.foo_id)

def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.foo[key]
```

And then you can do this:

```
foo_dict = {
    'id': 1
    'name': 'George'
    # ..other key values
}

hashable_foo = Foo(foo_dict)

print(hashable_foo['name']) # access like a normal dict
```