# How are Python dictionaries (builtin hashtables) implemented?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I was wondering how is the python `dict` (dictionary/hashtable) implemented. Particularly, if I write something like

```
my_dict = {"key": {"key: {"key": "value"}}}
```

what possibly does the python interpreter do? I want to know the internal working of it.

Does it treat each dictionary as an object (mostly yes)? If so, is the hashing same for same keys across different dictionaries? For e.g.

```
dict1 = {"key": "value", "k": "v"}
dict2 = {"key": [1, 2.], "k": "value"}
```

How different would the look-up for the keys in these 2 distinct dicts be? Also, how does it decide the size of the buckets? Or is similar to the handling of list size?
Hope you get my question. Thanks!

**EDIT** - No, I am not asking how hash-tables work. I know that part.

Comment: Are you asking if the hash function that is called for `dict1["key"]` is identical to the hash function that is called for `dict2["key"]`?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514716/overriding-pythons-hashing-function-in-dictionary

Comment: Can I flag my own question as duplicate? Because, I [found an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022835/2689986) but the question was not that specific.

Comment: All major implementations of python are open source. Feel free to look at the source.

Comment: Oops, I went too far in saying 'internal implementations'. I was asking for theoretical/descriptive explanations (not actual code) (got it in the duplicate questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python dictionary are basically the implementation of hash tables. Now, the question is what is hash table? From wikipedia, short and sweet answer:

> a hash table (also hash map) is a data structure used to implement an
>   associative array, a structure that can map keys to values
>   A hash table uses a hash function to compute an index into an array of buckets or slots, from which the correct value can be found.

These two questions in SO covers some of the things you are interested in:

[How are Python's Built In Dictionaries Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented)

[How can Python dict have multiple keys with same hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010222/how-can-python-dict-have-multiple-keys-with-same-hash)

I would be repeating the same things if I go any further.

Answer (score 0):

[The specification](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) reads

> Another useful data type built into Python is the dictionary (see
>   Mapping Types — dict). Dictionaries are sometimes found in other
>   languages as “associative memories” or “associative arrays”.
>   It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing
>   a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds
>   initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way
>   dictionaries are written on output.

And places items in memory in a deterministic fashion through a [hash function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)