# How to implement __cmp__() and __hash__() for my class?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, collections, python-2.x

I would like to write a class that can be used as a key in a hashable collections (e.g. in a `dict`). I know that user classes are by default hashable, but using `id(self)` would be the wrong thing here.

My class holds a `tuple` as member variable. Deriving from `tuple` doesn't seem like an option because in my constructor I don't get the same kind of arguments as a `tuple` constructor. But perhaps that's not a limitation?

What I need is basically the hash of a `tuple` the way a real tuple would give it.

`hash(self.member_tuple)` does just that.

The idea here is that two tuples can be equal without their `id` being equal.

If I implement my `__cmp__()` as follows:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    return cmp(self, other)
```

will this automatically resort to `hash(self)` for the comparison? ... or should I implement it as follows:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.member_tuple, other)
```

My `__hash__()` function is implemented to return the hash of the held `tuple`, i.e.:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.member_tuple)
```

Basically, how do `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` interact? I don't know whether in `__cmp__()` the `other` will already be a hash or not and whether I should compare against "my" hash (which would be the one of the held `tuple`) or against `self`.

So which one is the right one?

Can anyone shed any light on this and possibly point me to documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd not use `__cmp__` and stick to using `__eq__` instead. For hashing that is enough and you don't want to extend to being sortable here. Moreover, `__cmp__` has been removed from Python 3 in favour of the rich comparison methods (`__eq__`, `__lt__`, `__gt__`, etc.).

Next, your `__eq__` should return True when the member tuples are equal:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, ThisClass):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.member_tuple == other.member_tuple
```

Returning the `NotImplemented` singleton when the type of the `other` object is not the same is good practice because that'll delegate the equality test to the `other` object; if it doesn't implement `__eq__` or also returns `NotImplemented` Python will fall back to the standard `id()` test.

Your `__hash__` implementation is spot-on.

Because a hash is not meant to be unique (it is just a means to pick a slot in the hash table), equality is then used to determine if a matching key is already present or if a hash collision has taken place. As such `__eq__` (or `__cmp__` if `__eq__` is missing) is not called if the slot to which the object is being hashed is empty.

This does mean that if two objects are considered equal (`a.__eq__(b)` returns `True`), then their hash values must be equal too. Otherwise you could end up with a corrupted dictionary, as Python will no longer be able to determine if a key is already present in the hash table.

If both your `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods are delegating their duties to the `self.member_tuple` attribute, you are maintaining that property; you can trust the basic `tuple` type to have implemented this correctly.

See the [glossary definition of *hashable*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) and the [`object.__hash__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). If you are curious, I've written about how the `dict` and `set` types work internally:

- [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)
- [Overriding Python's Hashing Function in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514716/overriding-pythons-hashing-function-in-dictionary)

Comment: thanks. The last paragraph confuses me, though. How do I guarantee that the hash value is the same? Can I assume that when hashing a `tuple`? I cannot possibly know whether the hash of any other given `tuple` is the same as the hash of the member tuple, can I?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: you are delegating the hash function to the tuple the same way you are delegating the equality test, so you are maintaining that property just fine. If tuple ever started producing different hash values even for tuples that are equal then that'd be a far bigger problem and you can be assured that that'd be fixed *very* promptly.